# change pagination number when scroll in url javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem. I want to make page like this

https://www.idntimes.com/korea/kpop/matthew-suharsono/rekomendasi-lagu-dreamcatcher-untuk-pengantar-tidur-c1c2/5

I already can add the page number at the end of the URL. But when I'm in testing.html/4 and I want to refresh it, the page does not appear and shows the error "Cannot get testing.html/4". How to make it can refresh like usual?

[image]

Here's my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        .spinner {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="font-size: 60px;">
    <div class="news-content">

    </div>
    <div class="loading">
        <p>Loading Please Wait</p>
    </div>
    <script>

        function loadData(count) {
            fetch('/index.json')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(json => {
                    if (count < json.length) {
                        let text = document.createElement('p');
                        text.innerText = json[count].text;
                        document.querySelector('.news-content').append(text);
                        if (count > 0) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, `/testing.html/${count}`)
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        let count = 0
        window.addEventListener('load', loadData(count));

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                count += 1;
                loadData(count)
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As a start, try changing `/testing.html/${count}` to `/testing.html#${count}` because adding slash tells browser to visit some other page (which does not exist).

Comment: Some questions: 1. is the testing.html/1 page working? 2. What server are you using? 3. What URLs are supported by your server? Where is the definition for this?

Comment: @skobaljic technically it could be the same page, depending on how URLs are defined by the server Kentury is using. For example, if Apache is being used and Rewrite_URL is enabled and .htaccess defines `testing.html/$1` as 'testing.html?someparam=$1', then it's actually the same page. However, the error message looks to be non-generic. So we will need to find out more information about the server being used and its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using pure HTML files in an HTTP/HTTPS local server. When you are having this kind of instance of the server you are not dynamically generating pages because you don't have any server side setup behind the HTML file.

You can do this using queries and since your app doesn't contain any server backend use client Javascript to create a pagination concept.

Instead of having a route type system ( which is usually handled by controller on the backend ) use query system:

```
Instead of:
/testing.html/{PAGE_NUMBER}
Use:
/testing.html?page={PAGE_NUMBER}
```

To get `page` query in Javascript, use the following function:

```
function getPageNumber() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const page = urlParams.get('page');

  return page;
}
```

Then create a function where you would paginate the data ( assuming the data is an array ):

```
function paginateData(data, resultsPerPage, pageNumber) {
    // Chunk the data based on the limit
    let result = data.reduce((rows, key, index) => (index % resultsPerPage == 0 ? rows.push([key]) : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows, []);
    // Return the current page with index calculation
    return result[pageNumber - 1];
}
```

And the final code should be something like this:

```
function getData(data) {

  const RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 2;

  const currentPageNumber = Number(getPageNumber());

  const paginatedData = paginateData(data, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, currentPageNumber);

  // If paginated data is undefined return first page
  if (!paginatedData) {
    /*
      You can even redirect to /testing.html?page=1
    */
    return paginateData(data, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, 1);
  }

  return paginatedData;

}
```

All you are left with is to provide the function `getData` with an `data` parameter resembling an array type.